# How to make auto respond bot to new member joined in groups without type command

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

How to make auto respond bot to new member joined in groups without type command?

Look at this picture:
Bot send new text when users joined in groups
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When a user is added to a group, an `update` is sent to the bot. In it `message` field, there is another field, called `new_chat_members`, that contains an array of `User` objects that were added to the group. You should send the appropriate message when such an update is received. (You can use information provided in `User` objects to get information about those users, e.g. Their name, to include it into your message.)
[image]

Comment: I always receive `Forbidden: bot can't initiate conversation with a user`, that means this isn't possible (anylonger)?

Comment: @skjerns I think you are trying to send a private message message to them. A bot can never start a conversation with a user. The user must start a conversation with the bot in order for the bot to send message to them.

Comment: Indeed! Is there a way to send any kind of message just to the joining person (group rule reminder)? I've experimentes with InlineKeyboard and ForceReply, but can't get it to work.

Comment: @skjerns AFAIK, there is no way to send users private message if they have not started a convesation with your bot before.